# How to save files inside project folder using multer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I need to save files inside folder present inside project using Node.js.I am explaining my code below.

> server.js:

```
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.get('/addSupplierData',admin.addSupplierData);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('view/index.html',{"root": __dirname});
})
```

> route.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/' });
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'logo', maxCount: 1 }]);
exports.addSupplierData=function(req,res){
    var logo=req.body.logo;
}
```

I am also using angular.js for front end and my controller side code is given below.

```
var supplierData={'logo':file};
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/addSupplierData',
        data:supplierData,
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
},function errorCallback(response) {
})
```

The generated output of the variable `file` is given below.

```
Blob
$ngfName:"1.jpg"
name:"1.jpg"
size:8607
type:"image/jpeg"
```

I am using `ngFileUpload` to upload the files.Here i need when user will submit the data the will store inside the `upload` folder.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your middleware to your route...

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/' });
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'logo', maxCount: 1 }]);

app.get('/addSupplierData', cpUpload, admin.addSupplierData);
```

Comment: You mean i have to add `multer` inside server.js file ?

Comment: Yes, unless you use the included Router.